# libGDX how to add new DirectionalLight to environment

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

So I just recently discovered that libGDX allows for 3D rendering and I wanted to try it out myself. However I have been having an issue with directional light. Right now my environment is being lighten up with Ambient light:

```
envo = new Environment();
        envo.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1f));
```

Which is nice, however it doesn't give my any sort of depth perception because I want shadows. So after doing some research I discovered I need to add a DirectionalLight to the environment:

```
envo.add(new DirectionalLight());
```

However, eclipse doesn't like this because it says the method Environment.add() takes a BaseLight object and not a DirectionalLight object. However, I went into the library and discovered that DirectionalLight() extends BaseLight, so I don't know why I'm getting this error :/

```
public class DirectionalLight extends BaseLight {
```

Every tutorial that I found that had DirectionaLight seems to implement it by using Environment.add(), so why isn't this working for me? Was there a recent update and this doesn't work anymore?